# comparing values of two columns in sharepoint 2007 list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've two columns in sharepoint 2007 list. First column is "For this one idea patents have been selected/filed". I've YES NO radio buttons for this column. Second column is "Number of Patents". I've a dropdown of values 0 to 5. I want second column to appear only when YES radio button of previous column is checked. Can anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Why is it necessary to have two columns? You can build a view to only show results when "Number of Patents" = 0.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use JavaScript or jQuery in the form to achieve this.  Not something that can be done out of the box.

Comment: I am writing these sql server minus queries to run in automated framework.